# same numbers, different input methods, different outputs

Tags: javascript, math, random, bubble-sort

While bubble sorting an array, it will give different outputs depending on the method of input, manually it sorts correctly, random it won't. Any ideas? the goal is to sort the numbers from lowest to highest

I've already tried doing the same inputs manually as it does at random but it still didn't work for random.

```
    valores =["20", "78", "48", "55", "4"]
```

(same input in both functions)

```
let valores = []

function randomVals() {
    let cantidad
    valores = []

    if (rCantidad.value != '') {
        cantidad = Number(rCantidad.value)
    } else {
        cantidad = 15
    }

    for (let k = 0; k < cantidad; k++) {
        valores.push(((Math.random()) * 100).toFixed(0))
    }
    console.log(valores)
}


function agregarValor() {

    let val = Number(valor.value)

    valores.push(val)

    console.log(valores)

}

function bubbleSort(){ 

for (let j=0; j<valores.length; j++){
for (let i=j+1; i<valores.length; i++){
    if (valores[j]>valores[i]){
        var temp=0
        temp=valores[i]
        valores[i]=valores[j]
        valores[j]=temp
        console.log(valores)
    }
}
}
 }
```

expected sorted output:

```
     valores=[4, 20, 48, 55, 78]
```

sorted output given while using

```
      randomVals() valores=["20", "4", "48", "55", "78"]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a little bit more what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ShayeUlman I want the numbers to be ordered from lowest to highest.

Comment: You just want to sort the array, or you trying to figure out something /  to implement a sort function yourself (rather than using the built-in `sort()` function)?

Comment: @ShayeUlman I am sorting the array, using a bubble sort function, but it will only sort it correctly when the inputs are given by `agregarValor()`if they're given by `randomVals` it won't sort it correctly.

Comment: Please post all the code, things will become clearer:)

Comment: @ShayeUlman just did

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` is a formatting function. It will return a string that represents the given number. Once you have strings in your array, your sorting function will use string comparison to compare them (where "20" < "4").

Make sure that the array contains numbers, e.g. by removing the formatting:

```
valores.push(((Math.random()) * 100))
```

If you just want integers, use `Math.round()`.